# How to get the JsonResult of a ControllerAction into the ViewModel as a string without AJAX?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

So I've got a Controller action that takes a string and returns a JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult GetMemberJSON(string memberNumber)
{
      var t = new { foo = memberNumber }; // does more crap, greatly simplified here....
      return Json(t, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And I want to 'print' that JSON directly into the HTML of the View so that JavaScript that runs from that view can see the JSON at pageload. I do NOT want to Ajax in this JSON, there is no reason I can tell that I shouldn't be able to grab this JSON somehow in code.

My ViewModel that needs to hold this JSON is:

```
public class MakePaymentViewModel : IValidatableObject 
{
    public MyClassBlah Blah { get; set; }
    public string MemberJSONInfo { get; set }

    public void LoadThings(string memberNumber) 
    {
        this.Blah = MyClassBlah.Get(memberNumber);
        this.MemberJSONInfo = ""; // what goes here???
    }
}
```

And my View that will handle the JSON string as JavaScript code is:

```
<div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var json = @(new HtmlString(Model.MemberPACJSONInfo)); // mixing JS and Razor here....
            Library.PaymentDetailManager.BlockPACFieldsAsNeeded(json);
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

I know that I CAN get this to work if the Controller action returns String instead of JsonResult, but that feels wrong to me. Also, if I run the JsonResult through the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer() (which seems dumb to do), I get valid JSON, but it looks like:

```
// viewmodel
var cont = new MembershipCenter.Controllers.MembershipController();
var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonResult = cont.GetMemberJSON(this.Member.Id);
this.MemberPACJSONInfo = oSerializer.Serialize(jsonResult);

// here's how it renders in the View
{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":{"foo":"990006"},"JsonRequestBehavior":0}
```

Is the above the best I can ask for? I guess it can work, but I am wondering why calling ToString() on a JsonResult doesn't just print out the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ViewData dictionary to Save the JSON and use a ActionResult instead of a JSONResult and use this ViewData in the View

Comment: I'm not crazy about ViewData, but putting an ActionResult into the ViewData and then calling it in the view just renders out "System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult" on the screen. How can I get that to Execute() from the View?

Comment: What I meant is that you could do in the controller

    var oSerializer = new ystem.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    var jsonResult = cont.GetMemberJSON(this.Member.Id);

    ViewData["JSONData"] = oSerializer.Serialize(jsonResult);
    return View();

Answer (score 0):

Calling ToString() does not work because ToString() is not overridden in either JsonResult or ActionResult. ActionResults work by writing directly to the http response when ExecuteResult() is called.

Below is a snippet from JsonResult.ExecuteResult(). You can use the same code to serialize your "t" into MemberJSONInfo. Do not try to serialize the entire JsonResult.

```
  if (Data != null) {
     JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
  }
```

Comment: This is kind of what I am doing, serializing that object into a string member of the ViewModel. It just seems nuts to me that I have to do ANYTHING with a 'JsonResult' to get it to print out the JSON in a View!

Comment: You do *not* have to do anything with the JsonResult. Do not use it. I was only using that to show what it is going on behind the scenes. You can return a ViewResult with your supplied model. You just need to serialize "t" using the JSON serializer of your choice (in the example above I used the default MVC3 serializer).

Answer (score 0):

If you could re-factor code `var t = new { foo = memberNumber };` into a dependency, that can be used in multiple controllers.

I don't think instantiating controller and consume its method is good idea.